# Scrape airtable using Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, web-crawler

How can I scrape this site using Python3 ? https://airtable.com/shrpj2r4Kjc4YoMu4/tbl8m95GiuWehnIiT?blocks=hide

I already tried using requests library, and bs4, but the problem is that the site is generated dynamically, when you scroll down/up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a web crawler using a browser engine such as Chrome webdriver in Selenium. Then you can get the page sourcecode and do whatever you want with it.

Note that it is surprising that Airtable which is often used as a database to collect webscraped data from other websites does not allow easy webscraping itself. They recently (about a month ago) modified their permissions to prevent direct download of CSV files, so tools like airscraper can't work anymore. So you absolutely need to simulate a webbrowser to access airtable data.